# Newtonsoft deserialize a same date return different output

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

I'm deserializing a JSON using Newtonsoft for my Xamarin application, I am facing some issue when deserializing DateTime.

I have tried using the same code on asp.net C#, and storing the data into a dataset.  The C# gave me the right output.  However when it goes to Xamarin form, it produces the wrong output.

Expected result should be `2/4/2019 12:00:00 AM`.

I have no idea how the `4/1/2019 4:00:00PM` came from.

Wrong output using Xamarin

[image: Wrong Output]

Right output using C#

[image]

using Xamarin

```
public List<GetFleet> GetDefaults(string xUserID)
    {
        string inJson = 
        List<GetFleet> tempList = new List<GetFleet>();
        try
        {
            Uri serverUri2 = new Uri(inJson.ToString());

            string rs2 = RequestGeoHttpAsString(serverUri2);

            DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(rs2);

            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                tempList.Add(new GetFleet
                {
                    FleetID = row["registrationNumber"].ToString(),
                    FleetName = row["Location"].ToString(),
                    FleetIgnition = row["Ignition"].ToString(),
                    FleetFuel1 = row["sFuel1"].ToString(),
                    FleetStartTime = row["startTime"].ToString()

                });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exe = ex.Message;
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

using C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = 
        Uri serverUri2 = new Uri(url.ToString());

        string rs2 = RequestGeoHttpAsString(serverUri2);

        DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(rs2);

        DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);
        Response.Write(json);
    }

    public string RequestGeoHttpAsString(Uri address)
    {
        string result = "";


        // Create the web request  
        HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Get response  
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            // Read the whole contents and return as a string  
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual json which you are receiving? Looks suspiciously like you are getting different data.

Comment: I think, you are not looking at the same record. Also the values for `fuel1` differ. `190.60` vs. `191.16`

Comment: Couldn't be an issue with the time offset?

Comment: DateTime serialization will be affected by your locale settings - are you sure both systems you are testing with have the same locale?

Comment: Could it be a format issue ? Are you using a dateTime converter when Deserializing ?

Comment: Hi James, Derprischer.  The Fuel level is difference is due to the vehicle is moving, hence the fuel level will decrease from time to time.

Comment: Hi Jason, yes both systems are in the same locale.

Comment: Hi Umar3x, for the Xamarin Application, I did declare a class "GetFleet" to declare variables.  

`class GetFleet
    {
        public string FleetID { get; set; }
        public string FleetName { get; set; }
        public string FleetDesc { get; set; }
        public string FleetIgnition { get; set; }
        public string FleetFuel1 { get; set; }
        public string FleetStartTime { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: "I have tried using the same code on asp.net C#, and storing the data into a dataset." I want to know the code of storing the data. This need to check wheher 
the data already is different when storing . @ArthurLiew

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang, i add in the sample code of storing the data to dataset.  Please have a look and give me feedback on what mistake that I did.  Thanks alot for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I used another alternative solution on this matter.
I converted the date into string/VARCHAR in backend.
When it returns in JSON, it would be in text.